# Override invalid option message with getopts in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am using `getopts` to track options that are given to my script. However, I want to able to detect whether an option that was specified is invalid. I can do this, but it will always echo a message that I haven't written.

**The result**

```
my.sh: illegal option -- x
Error: Invalid option was specified --
```

**What I want to achieve**

```
Error: Invalid option was specified --
```

**A snippet of my code**

```
while getopts g:r: option; do
        case $option in
                g) guesses=$OPTARG;;
                r) range=$OPTARG;;
                ?) echo "Error: Invalid option was specified -- $OPTARG";;
        esac
done
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want two *short* options `-g` and `-r`, the following example will not trigger the `illegal option` message on passing `-x`:

```
while getopts ":g :r" option; do
    case $option in
        g) guesses=$OPTARG;;
        r) range=$OPTARG;;
        ?) echo "Error: Invalid option was specified -$OPTARG";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 4):

By adding `:` before the flags, I am telling `getopts` that I want to take control of flags that aren't in the list I set.

Answer (score 4):

In bash you can set OPTERR to 0 before commencing parsing:

```
OPTERR=0
while getopts 'option string' opt; do
    echo    "opt    = $opt"
    echo    "OPTIND = $OPTIND"
    echo    "OPTARG = $OPTARG"
    echo    "OPTERR = $OPTERR"
done
```